# Парсинг данных из json с сайта?

Tags: json, парсер

Есть страничка, сказали вывести оттуда данные из json в табличку с помощью любого ЯП.
Но уже при поиске json возникли проблемы)
В панели разработчика перешел на вкладку network, далее выбрал нужный файл. Кликаю preview и все что нужно отображается, значит выбрал правильно.
[image: Данные из json]

После чего я пошел в раздел Headers и скопировал url запроса, вставил и ничего) Пишет на странице "Cannot GET /calculator/validate"
Запрос POST, как показано в Headers, мб в адресной строке нужно добавить какие-то параметры еще?
[image: Тут url взят]

Comment: Добавлю сюда еще страницу если понадобится https://sport.insure/kalkulyator-strahovaniya/

Comment: https://curlconverter.com/

Comment: @СергейШ, а что цэ?:)

Comment: @СергейШ, я уже через командную строку пытался, мне вывелись данные. Вводил команду curl -X POST example.com, это единственный способ?